# How to retrieve publishing rollup image path in sharepoint object model

Tags: sharepoint

While using the traditional code to retrieve list items in SharePoint, Everytime I get an error whenever I try to read the value of publishing rollup image. My Code is as below:

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList myList = mySite.Lists["Quick Links"];
            SPListItemCollection myItems = myList.Items;
            for (int i = 0; i < myItems.Count; i++)
            {
                SPListItem item = myItems[i];
                pageHTML += item["PublishingRollupImage"].ToString(); //error
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method
item.GetFormattedValue("Rollup Image");

Answer (score 0):

The array access (bracket) notation to access a field value accepts one of three values between the brackets:

1. The field's GUID (as a `System.Guid`)
2. The field's display name (as a `string`)
3. The field's index in the item's fields collection (as an `integer`)

When accessing a field by its **internal name** instead of by its display name, you should use the dedicated `GetFieldByInternalName` method to retrieve the field from the fields collection, then use the retrieved field's `Id` property to get the field's GUID and use that in the brackets.

```
item[item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("PublishingRollupImage").Id].ToString();
```